# How to change a data frame in order to plot the data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, stock, price

I want to scrape multiple stocks from Yahoo finance, and convert the stocks to euro, if the stock is for instance in USD dollar of GBP. I have a code which converts the historical stocks to euro, with the date, but now I have to make the df that it is possible to plot the data correctly.
This is code I have now.

```
 import yfinance as yf
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
    
 start = '2013-01-01'
 end = '2021-01-01'
    
 rates = ['USDEUR=X', 'GBPEUR=X']
 tickers = yf.Tickers(' '.join(rates))
    
 exchange_rates = []
for i in range(len(tickers.tickers)):
    exchange_rates.append(tickers.tickers[i].history(start=start, end=end).Close)

ex_df = pd.DataFrame(exchange_rates).T
ex_df.columns = rates
ex_df['EUREUR=X'] = 1.0

assets = {'^AEX':'EUR', 'AAPL':'USD', 'AZN.L':'GBP', 'AD.AS':'EUR', 'ASML.AS':'EUR'}

  stock_df = pd.DataFrame()

for k,v in assets.items():
    data = yf.download(k, start=start, end=end, progress=False).Close.to_frame()
    data['ticker'] = k
    if v[:3] == 'EUR':
        data['rating'] = ex_df['EUREUR=X']
        data['price'] = data['Close'] / data['rating'] 
    elif v[:3] == 'USD':
        data['rating'] = ex_df['USDEUR=X']
        data['price'] = data['Close'] / data['rating'] 
    elif v[:3] == 'GBP':
        data['rating'] = ex_df['GBPEUR=X']
        data['price'] = data['Close'] / data['rating'] 
    else:
        data['rating'] = np.NaN
        data['price'] = np.NaN
stocks_df = pd.concat([stock_df, data], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will repost the full version of the code again.
It is the same for both `df.fillna()`. I also replaced the graph image.
Good luck.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start = '2020-07-01'
end = '2021-01-01'

rates = ['USDEUR=X', 'GBPEUR=X']
tickers = yf.Tickers(' '.join(rates))

exchange_rates = []
for i in range(len(tickers.tickers)):
    exchange_rates.append(tickers.tickers[i].history(start=start, end=end).Close)

ex_df = pd.DataFrame(exchange_rates).T
ex_df.columns = rates
ex_df['EUREUR=X'] = 1.0

assets = {'^AEX':'EUR', 'AAPL':'USD', 'AZN.L':'GBP', 'AD.AS':'EUR', 'ASML.AS':'EUR'}

stock_df = pd.DataFrame()
for k,v in assets.items():
    data = yf.download(k, start=start, end=end, progress=False).Close.to_frame()
    data['ticker'] = k
    if v[:3] == 'EUR':
        data['rating'] = ex_df['EUREUR=X']
        data['price'] = data['Close'] / data['rating'] 
    elif v[:3] == 'USD':
        data['rating'] = ex_df['USDEUR=X']
        data['price'] = data['Close'] / data['rating'] 
    elif v[:3] == 'GBP':
        data['rating'] = ex_df['GBPEUR=X']
        data['price'] = data['Close'] / data['rating'] 
    else:
        data['rating'] = np.NaN
        data['price'] = np.NaN

    stock_df = pd.concat([stock_df, data], axis=0)

my_stocks = stock_df.pivot(columns='ticker', values='price')
my_stocks.head()

ticker  AAPL    AD.AS   ASML.AS     AZN.L   ^AEX
Date                    
2020-06-30  102.574478  24.260000   326.899994  7694.486885     559.729980
2020-07-01  102.278087  23.879999   327.149994  7665.306388     562.669983
2020-07-02  102.418480  24.129999   332.750000  7758.488549     570.750000
2020-07-03  102.418480  23.870001   333.950012  7626.217088     568.630005
2020-07-06  105.119162  23.900000   343.549988  7810.244933     578.520020

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for c in my_stocks.columns.values[1:]:
    plt.plot(my_stocks.index, my_stocks[c], label=c)

plt.title('title')
plt.xlabel('Date',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Adj. Price € (EUR)',fontsize=18)

plt.legend(my_stocks.columns.values[1:], loc='center right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks again! after  my_stocks = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True) 
 I receive this error "initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame". I am sorry, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The cause of the error is due to a missing library. This is the code to read the data in the text format presented in the question. Since you already have the data, you can copy it from the line `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and you can draw the graph.

Comment: I already had imported that library. Could you please share the entire date here? I think I am doing something else wrong. If we share here the entire code, other users will have the entire code as well.

Comment: Have you checked the data? I have created the data and changed the graph. However, the acquisition period has been changed.

Comment: I have updated the code above, if I run my_stocks.head(), I will only see one stock. I have used your graph code.  I don't see anything in the graph. I think the issue is  that I did something wrong with the data frame (stock_df). Is it possible to clear the NA data, that If a data is missing, the code will use the last known price and or currency price? I need this data to calculate for instance the SMA of 50 and 200 days.

Comment: Replacing NA with a value is handled by `df.fillna()`; replacing it with 0 will remove the dashed line from the graph, but it will cause problems because the graph contains 0. If it looks like yours, you can use `df.fillna(method='fill',inplace=True)` to fill in the previous day's values and replace the original data frame.

Comment: Thanks again, but I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong, if I run the above code (which I put in the question) with your graph code, I don't see anything. Do I have to place  df.fillna(method='fill',inplace=True) just below the stock_df = pd.DataFrame() code?

Comment: I just copy+paste your code above in Google Colab and in Jupyter notebook. Unfortunately both programs did now show your results, after the code my_stocks.head() I just see only one ticker. And it is always the last ticker that is visible in my_stocks.head(). I don't see the information of the one ticker in the graph. I don't receive any errors. The only thing I could imagine is that I am Dutch, with maybe different keyboard settings?

Comment: I will delete your earlier comment once you are able to verify it with Google Colab. Please comment when you have confirmed.

Comment: The link you paste must have access rights. Please paste in a link that everyone can refer to.

Comment: Now you know why: the `stock_df = pd.concat([stock_df, data], axis=0)` in line 8 is the target of the loop processing, so don't make it a separate cell, move it to the bottom line of the previous loop.

Comment: There was also one unnecessary line mixed in. Also, I fixed the layout so that you can see the point loop process this time. The link to the collaboration will be removed.

Comment: I want to than you for your patience, the loop was indeed incorrectly place by me, in the way that the loop was not operated properly.  The code  works fine now! This was a hard start using Python. Let's delete all these comments?

Comment: I think it's better to delete only the comments with links.